# Validate if checkbox is checked with isset, every checkbox has same name

Tags: php, html

I have a checkbox group and every checkbox has de same name "horarios[]", because im saving it inside an array with php so then i can display the ones that were checked...

When validating i need to compare every single checkbox to a variable and see if its ok to send the mail..

The thing is how can i access every input individually to be validated??

I was guessing something like this, but does not work!

html:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='horarios[]' value='Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal' id="lun8" onclick="displaySelectedCheckBox(this)"/><label for="lun8"></label>

<button type="submit" id="submit" method="post" name="submit"></button>
```

php:

```
@$cuposlun8=14;

    if(isset($horarios['Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal']) && $cuposlun8>=14){
        echo '<script>alert("Cupos para lun8 agotados");</script>';
    }else{
        @mail($recipient, $subject, $mensaje, $header); //mail command :)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of array passed to PHP is horarios[] in PHP you can use foreach loop.

You check keys instead of values. So you need loop through all the values if all are set. It'll be good to set these values in array and do double foreach loop.

So instead of

```
if(isset($horarios['Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal'])
```

it'll look more like

```
$canSend = false;
foreach($horarios[] as $val)
{
   if($val == 'Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal') { $canSend = true; break; }
}
if($canSend) // send email there
```

Also the array in PHP can be get via `$_GET['horarios']` or `$_POST['horarios']` depends on your "method" in form tag.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will receive any group of inputs named `horarios[]` as an array. When you do not specify the array index (or key), it will automatically assume increasing integers starting at 0. In other words, it's the same as if you have a set of inputs like this:

```
<input name="horarios[0]" />
<input name="horarios[1]" />
<input name="horarios[2]" />
<input name="horarios[...]" />
```

So if you [`print_r($horarios)`](http://pt1.php.net/print_r), you'll get something like this (input index => input value):

```
Array(
    0 => 'Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal',
    1 => 'Second CHECKED input value',
    // [...] And so forth
)
```

As **PHP will only receive the checked inputs**, you'll have to iterate over them and make your validation within a `for` or `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to send the information using a form.

Then your HTML should look like this:

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input type='checkbox' name='horarios[]' value='Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal' id="$
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

on your PHP script you can check the contents of the POST parameters with `print_r($_POST)` (you can put it inside a pre-tag to easier reading).

In your case you are sending the data as follows

```
Array
(
    [horarios] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal
        )
)
```

So in your code you should be checking against $_POST['horarios'][$i] whose value will be one of the values you set your checkboxes. Your condition would look like:

```
if($_POST['horarios'][$i] == "Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal" && $cuposlun8>=14) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send a checkbox group name as horários[], you will convert it to na array. For each item in your checkbox group you will have a position in the array, in the exact order it was declared in you form.

For instance, if you submit a form with this three boxes:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='horarios[]' value='Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal'>
<input type='checkbox' name='horarios[]' value='Lunes 9:30hs-Clase grupal'>
<input type='checkbox' name='horarios[]' value='Lunes 10:30hs-Clase grupal'>
```

Then you get it in a $_POST variable as an array and the iterate on it to compare the values. Its importante to remember that if one of the checkbox is not checked, that position will not be registered in the array, so if you have three boxes and only two are checked, your array will have only two positions.

```
<?
$horarios = $_POST["horarios"];
foreach($horarios as $horario){

    if($horario == "Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal"){
        ...;
    } else if ($horario == "Lunes 9:30hs-Clase grupal"){
        ...;
    } else if ($horario == "Lunes 10:30hs-Clase grupal"){
        ...;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks men, although its not exactly how i made it work it really helped a lot!

Answer (score -1):

**do like this:**

```
<form action ='' method='post' name ='horarios'>
   <input type='checkbox' name='horarios[lun8]' value='Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal'    id="lun8" onclick="displaySelectedCheckBox(this)"/><label for="lun8"></label>

    <input  type="submit" id="submit"  name="submit"/>
</form>
```

**php**:

```
$cuposlun8=14;
$horarios = $_POST['horarios'];

if(isset($horarios['lun8']) && $horarios['lun8'] == 'Lunes 8:30hs-Clase grupal' && $cuposlun8>=14){
    echo '<script>alert("Cupos para lun8 agotados");</script>';
}else{
    mail($recipient, $subject, $mensaje, $header); //mail command :)
}
```